# Bidirectional OneToOne relation in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

### Outline of Problem

I'm having some issues creating a bidirectional OneToOne relationship in Symfony2 using Doctrine2. My database has two tables I'm trying to relate, CrmCapacity and CrmPackages, CrmCapacity has a field PackageId which matches to the Id field in CrmPackages.

I **am** able to get a capacity from a package, but I don't seem to be able to get a package from a capacity, as the relationship stands it's one directional not bidirectional.

Following is the code in my controller, this works just fine to access a capacity from a package.

```
$package = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('LargeAzureBundle:Package')
            ->find('ID-HERE');

var_dump($package->getName());
var_dump($package->getCapacity()->getIsIncompleteReason());
die();
```

That works fine, however the following fetches data for Capacity but not for Package

```
$capacity = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('LargeAzureBundle:Capacity')
    ->find('3FF564FC-5EA0-E211-B8AC-005056B70002');

var_dump($capacity->getIsIncompleteReason());
var_dump($capacity->getPackage()->getName());
die();
```

### Entities

Following are the annotations from my entities

**Package**

```
class Package {
    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Capacity", mappedBy="Package")
     */
    protected $Capacity;

    --SNIP--
}
```

**Capacity**

```
class Capacity {
    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Package", inversedBy="Capacity")
     * @JoinColumn(name="PackageId", referencedColumnName="Id")
     */
    protected $Package;

    --SNIP--
}
```

Any ideas? I'm a bit stumped on this one.

Comment: is it a typing mistake that both your classes are called Package??

Comment: Can you post the method to create entity elements? I guess that you don't do $package->addCapacity($elem);

Comment: I'm not adding any elements, just reading. I'm connecting to a read only MsSQL database via PDO_DBLIB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get an answer from memoryleak on the Symfony IRC channel. Setting a fetch attribute on the annotation worked in this case, for example;

```
class Capacity {
    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Package", inversedBy="Capacity", fetch="EAGER")
     * @JoinColumn(name="PackageId", referencedColumnName="Id")
     */
    protected $Package;

    --SNIP--
}
```